# filter array of objects based on list of values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have an array as following

```
array = [
{
  name: 'A'
  instructors: [
   {
     name:'InsA'
   }
  ]
  businessUnit: {name:'myBusiness'}
},
{
  name: 'B'
  instructors: [
   {
     name:'InsB'
   }
  ]
  businessUnit: {name:'myBusinessB'}
}

]
```

I want to filter this array with the values i have which are also in an array as following

```
nameArr = [A,C,D]
instructorArr = [InsA,InsC,InsZ]
businessName = [myBusinessB,myBusinessX,myBusinessD]
```

If can filter this array if i have to check with just one value as following

```
const filtered = _.filter(groupActivityList, (obj) => {
      return (
        obj.name === (groupClassFilter !== defaultFilter ? groupClassFilter : obj.name) &&
        obj.instructors.length > 0 &&
        obj.instructors[0]?.name ===
          (groupInstructorFilter !== defaultFilter
            ? groupInstructorFilter
            : obj.instructors.length > 0 && obj.instructors[0]?.name) &&
        obj.businessUnit.name ===
          (groupFacilityFilter !== defaultFilter ? groupFacilityFilter : obj.businessUnit.name)
      );
    });
```

How do i filter when i have a set of values to filter with Ex: `nameArr = [A,C,D]`

Answer (score 1):

An example for filtering the array using `Array.prototype.some` and `Array.prototype.includes`:

```js
const array = [{
    name: 'A',
    instructors: [{
      name: 'InsA'
    }],
    businessUnit: {
      name: 'myBusinessA'
    }
  },
  {
    name: 'B',
    instructors: [{
      name: 'InsB'
    }],
    businessUnit: {
      name: 'myBusinessB'
    }
  },
  {
    name: 'Z',
    instructors: [{
      name: 'InsZZ'
    }],
    businessUnit: {
      name: 'myBusinessZZ'
    }
  }
];

const nameArr = ['A', 'C', 'D']
const instructorArr = ['InsA', 'InsC', 'InsZ']
const businessName = ['myBusinessB', 'myBusinessX', 'myBusinessD', 'myBusinessA']

const filtered = array.filter(el => nameArr.includes(el.name) && el.instructors.some(ins => instructorArr.some(iA => ins.name === iA)) &&
  businessName.includes(el.businessUnit.name)
);
console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: how to return the data only when all 3 conditions are met? I have used && instead of || , but then it returns an empty array

Comment: @CraZyDroiD that's because the array doesn't have any elements matching all the conditions. updated the array to include an element that satisfies the filters, check now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Array#some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) property, if I understand the question correctly.

Instead of checking `obj.name === filterObj.name`, you can check with `fiterObj.names.some(name => name === obj.name)` which will return true if any of the elements inside the `namesArr` matches the object's name

Comment: I didn't edit on your filter function as you have different conditionals which does not belong to the question(like `groupFacilityFilter`, `defaultFilter` etc)